# How to know 7 inch and 10 inch tablet programmatically without screen dimension calculations

Tags: android

I want to know on which tablet, application is running at run time without screen calculation.  Likewise we make a drawable folder for image resource of different tablet sizes(e.g. drawable-sw600dp for 7" and drawable-sw720dp for 10").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this logic put these value in respective folders   like below

```
values-sw600dp//for seven inch

<bool name="isSmallerTablet">true</bool>

values-sw720dp//for other tablets.

<bool name="isSmallerTablet">false</bool>
```

and use it in activity like this

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isSmallerTablet)){

}
```

Comment: It is the more elegant way!

Answer (score 1):

Let the platform do the detection for you!

Create a file res/values-sw600dp/screensize.xml and put in this file integer value of 7

```
<resources>
    <integer name="size">7</integer>
</resources>
```

Create a file res/values-sw720dp/screensize.xml and put in this file integer value of 10

```
<resources>
    <integer name="size">10</integer>
</resources>
```

Now at runtime, simply check the value `R.integer.size` to get your size.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it depend on width size on screen 720 belongs to 10'' tablet and 600 belongs to 7'' tablet.

[image]

For more info you can refer here

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html